No driver for MIPI-DSI display in Linux kernel, but there is in U-Boot, is it going to work?
I'm going to buy a MIPI-DSI display for my single board computer. The display has SSD2828 chip inside. There is no driver for it in linux kernel 'linux/drivers/gpu/drm', but i found one in u-boot source 'u-boot/drivers/video/ssd2828.c'. So if my computer uses u-boot as a bootloader, which then boots linux kernel, will my display work?

https://linux-sunxi.org/SSD2828
